# How to improve query efficiency in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I need to export a portion of database with the function apoc.export.cyphe.data().
Here's the code which I use to call the function:

```
MATCH path = (p1:Author)-[r:CO_AUTHORSHIP]-(p2:Author) WITH collect(p1)+collect(p2) as 
export_nodes,collect(r) as export_rels CALL 
apoc.export.cypher.data(export_nodes,export_rels,'/tmp/export.cypher',{format:'cypher- 
shell',cypherFormat: 'updateAll'}) YIELD file, source, format, nodes, relationships, 
properties,timeRETURN nodes, relationships, time
```

The problem is that the query
MATCH path = (p1:Author)-[r:CO_AUTHORSHIP]-(p2:Author)
takes more than an hour!

I have a database with 467437 CO_AUTHORSHIP relationships. Each node of the database represent an author. For each relationship edge I store data about articles (number of articles, types, venues, titles and years) written by both the authors.

I there a way to improve the efficiency of that query?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is putting each `Author` into `export_nodes` multiple times, and each `CO_AUTHORSHIP` relationship into `export_rels` multiple times. This should be faster and use less memory:

```
MATCH path = (a:Author)-[r:CO_AUTHORSHIP]-()
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS export_nodes, COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS export_rels
CALL apoc.export.cypher.data(
  export_nodes, export_rels, '/tmp/export.cypher', 
  {format:'cypher-shell', cypherFormat: 'updateAll'}) YIELD nodes, relationships, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time
```